# jQuery Fullcalendar, the Date (2011,12,25) shows up as 25th of Jan 2012

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

All the dates i put on fullcalendar are a month ahead, 10 shows as nov, 11 shows as dec etc. Anyone got any idea why this is happening? If you gotta see any of my code just say so and ill post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the fulltext calendar but i do no that the javascript date object starts counting the months with zero.
Probly that is why the fullcalendar also has this behavior.

Comment: +1 for this. I guess you did not consider the fact that January is month number 0. EDIT: Common mistake, not being rude.